# Is it possible to enable EPT on poweredge T110 II?

Tags: windows, docker

It seems that I need to enable EPT in order to play/learn more about Docker.
(Running win server 2016 in a VM)
I have run CoreInfo and I can see that EPT is not supported on my cpu.
When I google the cpu I find that EPT is supported: [Intel](https://ark.intel.com/products/53422/Intel-Core-i3-2100-Processor-3M-Cache-3_10-GHz)
Which is true? How to enable EPT?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use extended page tables if virtualization is disabled, as this is an extension to virtualization (VT-x) in the first place.

This particular Dell server ships with [virtualization disabled](https://downloads.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-t110-2_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf) in the BIOS. Check the BIOS settings under Processor Settings and enable virtualization.

Comment: Virtualization is already enabled since I'm running win server 2016 in a VM as stated.  I'm having a bit of trouble to reach that machine now, so I was hoping some one could confirm that it will be possible.
I will check BIOS to see if there is more to enable such as EPT etc when I have access.

Comment: If you're in a VM, then your hypervisor must have nested virtualization enabled. How you do this depends on the hypervisor. You could also run Docker on Linux directly, which doesn't have this limitation as Docker on Windows does.

Comment: I get mixed info. CoreInfo says no to EPT, Intel website says yes.
I would like to know if there are any cpu limitations before spending hours/days learning docker.
Not sure what you mean by "How you do this depends on the hypervisor."
Running docker on linux to avoid this is a great tip, but I think it will take me too much time to get it up and running.

Comment: You said you are running Windows in a VM, but you didn't mention the hypervisor.

Comment: Aaah, sorry. Im using Hyper-v.